# Бежать и тікати, или Загадочный побег

Tags: однокоренные-слова, этимология, морфемный-разбор

Возникла интересное соответствие между словом **побег**, в котором чувствуется корень -бег-, и украинским глаголом *тікати*, что значит "бежать" (напрашивается аналогия с корнем -тек-, -теч-, отчего кажется, будто бежать - это словно *утекать*: с течением воды, быстро, как стремительный поток). Слово *побег* я в словарях не встретила, полагаю, оно довольно ново, но вот в чём основной вопрос: почему здесь именно такой корень? Неужто росток стремительно *бежит*? :-)

Comment: "И тот послушно в путь потек и к утру возвратился с ядом!" - А.С.Пушкин, "Анчар"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В современном русском языке только в наречии наутек сохранилась память об изначальном значении слова течь -двигаться быстро.
У Даля: ТЕЧЬ - Нестись, бежать, идти быстро, мчаться. Облака текут от запада. Перелетная птица течет стаями. Белка течет(сибирское)кочует, переносится, пошла в ход. Текут гонцы во все концы.  Он тикет(курское) бежит. Тикай!(калужское) беги, уходи; тикать(малороссийск) бежать от чего, уйти, скрыться.

Если говорить об этимологии, то тикать - от праслав. *tekti, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. теку, течи «течь; двигаться; бежать», теча м. «скороход», ст.-слав. текѫ, тешти (др.-греч. τρέχω), аор. тѣшѩ, русск. теку, течь, укр. тiкати, тiка́ю «бежать», болг. тека́ «теку», сербохорв. тѐче̑м, тѐħи, словенск. téči, téčem «течь, бежать», оно родственно чешск. , словацк.  польск. и др.словам в этом значении.

Побег как ботанический термин - перевод с лат.córmus - единый организм из стебля, листьев и почек,имеющий возможность быстрого роста, - росток.

Побег откуда-то и побег растения - омонимы,но если захотеть, можно найти некие общие признаки: растение словно устраивает бегство из-под земли, выбрасывая новый росток, а в общем-то и то и другое связано с быстрым движением - человек бежит и росток бежит вверх, быстро движется в росте.

Интересны и другие термины в ботанике, связанные с движением:

Выгонка — прерывание полного покоя растений и получение цветочной продукции в намеченный срок путем создания им соответствующих условий.

"Отпрыск" раньше имело только одно значение - вторичный или боковой побег, образовавшийся от почки на срезе, корне или корневище.
Произошло слово от глагола "прыскать, прыщать, прыснуть" со значением "стремительно, внезапно прорываться, выскакивать", то есть побег как бы прорывается, выскакивает из почки, и потому и был назван "отпрыск", а потом уже стали так называть детей(чадо), это уже переносное значение.

Comment: Людмила, огромное спасибо! Это то, что я и надеялась прочесть!

Answer (score 1):

Основным значением глагола бежать  является **быстрое перемещение**, но у него есть **дополнительные значения,** связанные с видимостью быстрого перемещения, основанные на метафоре: **Простираться в каком-л. направлении; тянуться (обычно цепочкой, вереницей и т.п.)**. Дорога бежала вверх. Вдоль улицы бежали телеграфные столбы. Из-под пера бегут чёткие строки.

Также из словаря: 1. ПОБЕГ,  Самовольный уход из мест заключения, из места вынужденного пребывания и т.п.  2. ПОБЕГ,  Молодой стебель растения вместе с листьями и почками; отросток.

Эти значения связаны не с быстрым перемещением, а со смещением в сторону.

Comment: В этимологических словарях "побега" нет. Это относительно новое слово?

Comment: В этимологических словарях производные формы рассматриваются редко, но, к примеру, словарь Черных в этом отношении является исключением. Там в словарной статье глагола "бежать" указано, когда появились "беглец (раньше был бегун), беготня, беженец, но "побега" там нет.  Время появления этого слова надо искать в каких-то других источниках.